# In a systemd initrd, how do I persist a mount into the new root

Tags: systemd, initrd, dracut

#### Background

I'm building a custom initrd using dracut. It:

- mounts an ext4 disk partition to `/data`
- retrieves a squashfs image over the network, which it stores in `/data`
- mounts the squashfs
- mounts an overlayfs to `/sysroot`, with the squashfs image as the lower, and `/data/overlay` as the upper dir
- bind mount `/data` to `/sysroot/data`

The last step is done so that in the new root I can write new images to the data filesystem, and so that I can examine what is being overlayed. As far as I know, this can't be done in the new root.

I'm implementing these mounts with systemd.mount units, e.g. for the last mount:

```
[Unit]
After=sysroot.mount
After=data.mount

[Mount]
Where=/sysroot/data
What=/data
Type=none
Options=bind

[Install]
WantedBy=initrd.target
```

#### Question

Unfortunately, systemd is unmounting `/sysroot/data` before the switch_root. It is also trying to unmount `/data` and the squashfs image, but that fails since they are in use.

Is there a way to tell systemd to keep these mounts? I've read the [document](https://systemd.io/ROOT_STORAGE_DAEMONS/) on how to do this for storge daemons, but they don't specify how to do this for mounts.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do a bind mount of /data to /sysroot/data.

Once you are out of the initrd you can mount the block device again, without any issues, eg `mount /dev/sda1 /data`